# I want to set as null if element not present in Array

Tags: java

```java
public class TEST {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String role1=null,role2=null,role3=null,role4=null,role5=null;
         String role1Alloc=null,role2Alloc=null,role3Alloc=null,role4Alloc=null,role5Alloc=null;
                
         LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
         lhm.put("a", 6);
         lhm.put("b", 4);
         lhm.put("c", 7);
                
         String[] Keys = new String[lhm.size()];
         Integer[] Values = new Integer[lhm.size()];
         int i = 0;
         for (Map.Entry mapElement : lhm.entrySet()) {
             String key = (String) mapElement.getKey();
             int value = ((int) mapElement.getValue());
             Keys[i] = key;
             Values[i] = value;
             i++;
         }
                
         role4=Keys[4];// java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 3
         // but  i want set role4 as null if element is not present in array
    role4Alloc=Values[4];//java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds forlength 3
         // but  i want set role4Alloc  as null if element is not present in array  
                
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: A simple check with an `if` statement would do the trick... `if (Keys.length > 4) role4Alloc=Keys[4]; else role4Alloc = null;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3 elements in the `LinkedHashMap` and so when you initialized the array with `lhm.size()` it will initialize the `Array` with size 3 and so if you try to access 4th index in the array you will obviously get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: yes, you're right. but i need to call 4th element even if element is not exists and want to be set null instead of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: than you need to initialize the array with length greater than 4